# Repeating x and y vectors for use with scatter3()

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

Currently I have a working 3D `mesh()` plot. However, the vertical axis lends itself better to an angular representation, so I'm constructing a coordinate transform to cylindrical space, after which I'll plot everything with `scatter3()`.

Currently I have one-dimensional vectors containing all of the possible x and y values; however, they do not repeat (and they need to, to work in `scatter3()`). I have to flatten my two-dimensional z-matrix using `z(:)`. Is there a quick method to repeat `x` and `y` to also be `scatter3`-compatible?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/meshgrid.html) and then flatten:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
scatter3(X(:), Y(:), z(:));
```